# true vs predicted plot scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I want a scatter plot of true vs predicted. This is how the dataframe looks:

```
  predicted true
0     3      3
1     2      2
2     3      2
3     2      2
4     3      2
```

I did try using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data.true)
plt.plot(data.predicted, 'o')

plt.show()
```

I got this plot

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

This doesn't seem to be the right plot. So, could someone please help me with this?

Comment: You do not have any values for the x axis (unless the index values are really the x axis values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas [plot.scatter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

```
df.plot.scatter(x="true", y="predicted")
```